# Multiple definitions gives no errors or warnings in either gcc or clang

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, clang, warnings

If I did

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a; //definition
int a; //definition
int a; //definition
int a; //definition
int a; //definition
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

For example, I would get no errors or warnings from either gcc or clang despite defining a variable multiple times. Why? I thought I was allowed to declare a variable as many times as I wanted to, but could only define it once?

Answer (score 2):

This is a tentative definition. That is each declaration of a file scope variable without an initializer is considered as a declaration not as a definition. The definition is implicitly generated at the end of the translation unit with an initializer equal to 0.

From the C Standard (6.9.2 External object definitions)

> 2 A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
> without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
> the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative
> definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
> definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
> external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
> as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
> identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
> unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

Comment: That explains why it doesn't generate an error, but a warning might still be appropriate. Is it because it's common to have multiple tentative definitions from different header files?

Comment: @Barmar I think the compiler can have an option that sets a warning. For example for multiple function declarations some compilers by default issue a warning.

Comment: I tried `-Weverything` on my Mac, it didn't warn about this.

Comment: @Barmar It seems that developers of compilers do not think that it is required. :)

Comment: Clearly, although it seems like an obvious thing to warn about unless there's a good reason not to.